Как выровнять кнопки по левому краю в tkinter
Вот код:
import tkinter as tk
import math


def fact():
    try:
        result.set(math.factorial(int(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')

def sqrt():
    try:
        result.set(math.sqrt(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')

def logo():
    try:
        result.set(math.log(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')

def acos():
    try:
        result.set(math.acos(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def asin():
    try:
        result.set(math.asin(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def atan():
    try:
        result.set(math.atan(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def acosh():
    try:
        result.set(math.acosh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def asinh():
    try:
        result.set(math.asinh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def atanh():
    try:
        result.set(math.atanh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def cosh():
    try:
        result.set(math.cosh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def sinh():
    try:
        result.set(math.sinh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def tanh():
    try:
        result.set(math.tanh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def cos():
    try:
        result.set(math.cos(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def sin():
    try:
        result.set(math.sin(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def tan():
    try:
        result.set(math.cosh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("ComPortable Calculator version 1.2.0")
root.geometry('260x400')  

# canvas = tk.Canvas
# canvas.create_line(900, 30, 5, 30)

num = tk.StringVar()
result = tk.StringVar()

numb = tk.Label(root, text="Number")
numb.grid(column=2, row=1)

numbenter = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=num)
numbenter.grid(column=3, row=1)

b1 = tk.Button(root, text="Factorial", command=fact)
b1.grid(column=0, row=1)

b2 = tk.Button(root, text="Sqrt", command=sqrt)
b2.grid(column=0, row=2)

b3 = tk.Button(root, text="Logarithm", command=logo)
b3.grid(column=0, row=3)

b4 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcCos", command=acos)
b4.grid(column=0, row=4)

b5 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcSin", command=asin)
b5.grid(column=0, row=5)

b6 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcTan", command=atan)
b6.grid(column=0, row=6)

b7 = tk.Button(root, text="Cos", command=cos)
b7.grid(column=0, row=7)

b8 = tk.Button(root, text="Sin", command=sin)
b8.grid(column=0, row=8)

b9 = tk.Button(root, text="Tan", command=tan)
b9.grid(column=0, row=9)

b10 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcCosH", command=acosh)
b10.grid(column=0, row=10)

b11 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcSinH", command=asinh)
b11.grid(column=0, row=11)

b12 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcTanH", command=atanh)
b12.grid(column=0, row=12)

b13 = tk.Button(root, text="CosH", command=cosh)
b13.grid(column=0, row=13)

b14 = tk.Button(root, text="SinH", command=sinh)
b14.grid(column=0, row=14)

b15 = tk.Button(root, text="TanH", command=tanh)
b15.grid(column=0, row=15)


result1 = tk.Label(root, text="Результат")
result1.grid(column=2, row=3)
result2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=result, state='readonly')
result2.grid(column=3, row=3)
root.mainloop()


У метода .grid() есть параметр sticky для прилипания виджета к указанным сторонам ячейки грида. Например, если указать tk.W, то прилипнет к "западной" (west) стороне, т.е. к левой:
b1 = tk.Button(root, text="Factorial", command=fact)
b1.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W)

b2 = tk.Button(root, text="Sqrt", command=sqrt)
b2.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.W)

b3 = tk.Button(root, text="Logarithm", command=logo)
b3.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.W)

b4 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcCos", command=acos)
b4.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=tk.W)

b5 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcSin", command=asin)
b5.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=tk.W)

b6 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcTan", command=atan)
b6.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky=tk.W)

b7 = tk.Button(root, text="Cos", command=cos)
b7.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=tk.W)

b8 = tk.Button(root, text="Sin", command=sin)
b8.grid(column=0, row=8, sticky=tk.W)

b9 = tk.Button(root, text="Tan", command=tan)
b9.grid(column=0, row=9, sticky=tk.W)

b10 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcCosH", command=acosh)
b10.grid(column=0, row=10, sticky=tk.W)

b11 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcSinH", command=asinh)
b11.grid(column=0, row=11, sticky=tk.W)

b12 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcTanH", command=atanh)
b12.grid(column=0, row=12, sticky=tk.W)

b13 = tk.Button(root, text="CosH", command=cosh)
b13.grid(column=0, row=13, sticky=tk.W)

b14 = tk.Button(root, text="SinH", command=sinh)
b14.grid(column=0, row=14, sticky=tk.W)

b15 = tk.Button(root, text="TanH", command=tanh)
b15.grid(column=0, row=15, sticky=tk.W)


Если указать tk.EW (East-West), то все виджеты расширятся под ширину своих ячеек, и станут одного размера по ширине:
b1 = tk.Button(root, text="Factorial", command=fact)
b1.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.EW)

b2 = tk.Button(root, text="Sqrt", command=sqrt)
b2.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.EW)

b3 = tk.Button(root, text="Logarithm", command=logo)
b3.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.EW)

b4 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcCos", command=acos)
b4.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=tk.EW)

b5 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcSin", command=asin)
b5.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=tk.EW)

b6 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcTan", command=atan)
b6.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky=tk.EW)

b7 = tk.Button(root, text="Cos", command=cos)
b7.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=tk.EW)

b8 = tk.Button(root, text="Sin", command=sin)
b8.grid(column=0, row=8, sticky=tk.EW)

b9 = tk.Button(root, text="Tan", command=tan)
b9.grid(column=0, row=9, sticky=tk.EW)

b10 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcCosH", command=acosh)
b10.grid(column=0, row=10, sticky=tk.EW)

b11 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcSinH", command=asinh)
b11.grid(column=0, row=11, sticky=tk.EW)

b12 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcTanH", command=atanh)
b12.grid(column=0, row=12, sticky=tk.EW)

b13 = tk.Button(root, text="CosH", command=cosh)
b13.grid(column=0, row=13, sticky=tk.EW)

b14 = tk.Button(root, text="SinH", command=sinh)
b14.grid(column=0, row=14, sticky=tk.EW)

b15 = tk.Button(root, text="TanH", command=tanh)
b15.grid(column=0, row=15, sticky=tk.EW)


Параметры можно брать из tkinter - типа tk.NSEW, но можно складывать одиночные tk.W + tk.E, либо использовать просто строку вида "nsew".

Чтобы настроить размер кнопки, мы можем использовать свойства ширины и высоты виджета кнопки.
import tkinter as tk
import math


def fact():
    try:
        result.set(math.factorial(int(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')

def sqrt():
    try:
        result.set(math.sqrt(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')

def logo():
    try:
        result.set(math.log(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')

def acos():
    try:
        result.set(math.acos(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def asin():
    try:
        result.set(math.asin(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def atan():
    try:
        result.set(math.atan(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def acosh():
    try:
        result.set(math.acosh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def asinh():
    try:
        result.set(math.asinh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def atanh():
    try:
        result.set(math.atanh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def cosh():
    try:
        result.set(math.cosh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def sinh():
    try:
        result.set(math.sinh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def tanh():
    try:
        result.set(math.tanh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def cos():
    try:
        result.set(math.cos(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def sin():
    try:
        result.set(math.sin(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')
def tan():
    try:
        result.set(math.cosh(float(num.get())))
    except ValueError:
        result.set('Invalid input')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("ComPortable Calculator version 1.2.0")
root.geometry('260x400')  

# canvas = tk.Canvas
# canvas.create_line(900, 30, 5, 30)

num = tk.StringVar()
result = tk.StringVar()

numb = tk.Label(root, text="Number")
numb.grid(column=2, row=1)

numbenter = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=num)
numbenter.grid(column=3, row=1)


# -----------------------------------> vvvvvvvv <-----------------  !!! +++ 
b1 = tk.Button(root, text="Factorial", width=10, command=fact)
b1.grid(column=0, row=1)

b2 = tk.Button(root, text="Sqrt", width=10, command=sqrt)
b2.grid(column=0, row=2)

b3 = tk.Button(root, text="Logarithm", width=10, command=logo)
b3.grid(column=0, row=3)

b4 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcCos", width=10, command=acos)
b4.grid(column=0, row=4)

b5 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcSin", width=10, command=asin)
b5.grid(column=0, row=5)

b6 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcTan", width=10, command=atan)
b6.grid(column=0, row=6)

b7 = tk.Button(root, text="Cos", width=10, command=cos)
b7.grid(column=0, row=7)

b8 = tk.Button(root, text="Sin", width=10, command=sin)
b8.grid(column=0, row=8)

b9 = tk.Button(root, text="Tan", width=10, command=tan)
b9.grid(column=0, row=9)

b10 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcCosH", width=10, command=acosh)
b10.grid(column=0, row=10)

b11 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcSinH", width=10, command=asinh)
b11.grid(column=0, row=11)

b12 = tk.Button(root, text="ArcTanH", width=10, command=atanh)
b12.grid(column=0, row=12)

b13 = tk.Button(root, text="CosH", width=10, command=cosh)
b13.grid(column=0, row=13)

b14 = tk.Button(root, text="SinH", width=10, command=sinh)
b14.grid(column=0, row=14)

b15 = tk.Button(root, text="TanH", width=10, command=tanh)
b15.grid(column=0, row=15)


result1 = tk.Label(root, text="Результат")
result1.grid(column=2, row=3)
result2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=result, state='readonly')
result2.grid(column=3, row=3)
root.mainloop()



Я хотел бы добавить к комментариям уважаемых консультантов, что нет нужды стучать лишний раз по клавиатуре, а именно, вместо sticky=tk.W можно писать sticky="w". В других аналогичных командах типа tk.END - то же самое.
А в чём собственно проблема? Да никакой вобщем-то. Кроме той, что можно не привязываться намертво к имечку "tk".

Проблемы нет, просто вы заменили привязку к именам, которые импортированы из tkinter, и которые подскажет при вводе любая современная IDE, на привязку к строкам, где в написании очень легко ошибиться.

Конкретно в данном случае - это скорее вопрос предпочтений, вполне можно и так, и так (но лучше не смешивать в рамках одного проекта). Ну и см. последнее предложение в моем ответе, я про использование строк писал.
